# Increasing text output speed wedge scanner

Tags: windows-mobile, qr-code, barcode-scanner, symbols, pocketpc

I have a Symbol MC-50 pocket PC and I'm trying to scan a QR-code with a lot data. To be precise: 256 characters.

The text has been compressed to the max, so I can't decrease the amount of data.
When I'm scanning the QR-code, the scanner takes up to 3 seconds to output the text in the input field.

I am using the standard wedge apllication.
How can I increase the text output speed?

Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but I don know, if Motorola/Symbol supports any performance settings with there DataWedge. I know that Intermec provides performance settings for there VirtualWedge via VWconfig.ini.

I downloaded the DataWedge package of http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB100417&sliceId=&dialogID=446344460&stateId=1%200%20446328342, unfortunately there is no setting mentioned in the doc that enables performance tuning.

OK, the cause of the slow input is that an app can not flodd the message queue with WM_KEY messages without any delay in between the msgs. If the wedge has to 'simulate' a key press, it has to send three or more messages for every key. One key down, one key char and one key up message. If there is a delay of 2 ms in between the messages, the output of 256 low letter chars would need 256*3*2ms = 1536ms = 1.5 seconds.If there are upper chars or symbols within the string to wedge, the worse case would be 256*5*2ms=2.5 seconds. An upper char or some symbols need an additional shift key press/release before/after each char.

If you contact motorola support, ask if they support any inter-character delay setting. I have found with the Intermec VirtualWedge I can go down to 1ms delay without using chars.

BUT, the best would be to rewrite your app to use the Motorola SDK to access the scanner directly, if you are the coder.

regards

Josef

Comment: I'll look at it, thank you very much! I'll post the outcome here.